# LibGDX camera.project() is not working properly

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I use Box2D to manage my game world. I want to display text above the body. I plan to do this by setting the Label appropriately. The problem is that the body is in the game world and the Label is in the Stage (UI). So I tried to use the *camera.project()* method to convert world coordinates to screen coordinates. Unfortunately, for some reason I couldn't do it - the Label is displayed in a different place than it should be - it is shifted down and to the left relative to the target position. When resizing the window, this position also changes, but also incorrectly.
I will add that otherwise I use the *camera.unproject()* method in the same way and I have no problems here - everything works fine. I don't know why it's different the other way around.

```
this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(ScreenManager.WIDTH * SCALE, ScreenManager.HEIGHT * SCALE);
this.viewport = new FitViewport(ScreenManager.WIDTH, ScreenManager.HEIGHT);
this.stage = new Stage(viewport, batch);
this.world = new World(Vector2.Zero, true);

// ...

Vector3 worldPosition = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
Vector3 screenPosition = camera.project(worldPosition,
    viewport.getScreenX(), viewport.getScreenY(),
    viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight());

label.setPosition(screenPosition.x, screenPosition.y);
```

And my resize method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
}
```

Of course I call *act()* and *draw()* for Stage in the render method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could It be that the projecting is done twice? Stage.draw() calls batch.setProjectionMatrix(), and if that is set the batch automatically projects all coordinates.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: SpriteBatch has a setProjectionMatrix() method that once called will allow the SpriteBatch to do the coordinate conversion by itself. So when drawing, you just pass the world coordinates and dont have to bother calling project(). Stage.draw() calls batch.setProjectionMatrix() right before it starts drawing. If you call project yourself, the coordinates will be projected twice. Try just passing the coordinate as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to translate from `World`-coordinates to `Stage`-coordinates you need to first project the `World` position onto *screen-space*, and then unproject it back into *`Stage`-space*.

```
Vector2 worldPosition = body.getPosition();
Vector3 screenPosition = worldCamera.project(new Vector3(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y, 1.0f));
Vector3 stagePosition = stage.getCamera().unproject(screenPosition);

label.setPosition(stagePosition.x, stage.getHeight() - stagePosition.y)); // stage.getHeight() - because UP is flipped.
```

That process will allow you to track a **Box2D** `Body` and set a `Label`s position to match it:

[image: Label tracking Box2D body]

Full source for the example above is included below, it uses the default font from the **libGDX** tests ([font](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/default.fnt) and the [font image](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/default.png)).

```
package com.bornander.sandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class MyGdxSandbox extends ApplicationAdapter {
    World world;
    OrthographicCamera worldCamera;
    Box2DDebugRenderer box2DDebugRenderer;

    Body ballBody;
    Stage stage;
    Label label;
    
    @Override
    public void create () {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, -10.0f), false);
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float worldCameraViewportWidth = 100.0f;
        worldCamera = new OrthographicCamera(worldCameraViewportWidth, worldCameraViewportWidth / aspectRatio);
        worldCamera.position.set(worldCamera.viewportWidth / 2.0f, worldCamera.viewportHeight / 2.0f, 1.0f);
        box2DDebugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        CircleShape ballShape = new CircleShape();
        ballShape.setRadius(4.0f);

        FixtureDef ballFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        ballFixtureDef.shape = ballShape;
        ballFixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
        ballFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        ballFixtureDef.restitution = 0.65f;

        BodyDef ballBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        ballBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        ballBody = world.createBody(ballBodyDef);
        ballBody.createFixture(ballFixtureDef);
        ballBody.setTransform(25, 50, 0);
        ballBody.applyLinearImpulse(200, 0, ballBody.getPosition().x, ballBody.getPosition().y, true);

        PolygonShape groundShape = new PolygonShape();
        groundShape.setAsBox(25, 2);

        FixtureDef groundFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        groundFixtureDef.shape = groundShape;
        groundFixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
        groundFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        groundFixtureDef.restitution = 0.2f;

        BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        groundBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

        Body ground = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);
        ground.createFixture(groundFixtureDef);
        ground.setTransform(50, 20, 0);


        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        stage.setDebugAll(true);
        label = new Label("TEXT", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("default.fnt")), Color.WHITE));
        label.setPosition(10, 10);
        stage.addActor(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 1);
        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        worldCamera.update();
        world.step(delta, 8, 8);
        Vector2 ballPositionWorld = ballBody.getPosition();
        Vector3 ballScreenPosition = worldCamera.project(new Vector3(ballPositionWorld.x, ballPositionWorld.y, 1.0f));
        Vector3 ballStagePosition = stage.getCamera().unproject(ballScreenPosition);
        label.setText(String.format("(%.3f, %.3f)", ballPositionWorld.x, ballPositionWorld.y));
        label.pack();
        label.setPosition(ballStagePosition.x, stage.getHeight() - ballStagePosition.y);
        box2DDebugRenderer.render(world, worldCamera.combined);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It actually works. I have one more question. I noticed that the Label text doesn't follow the body smoothly, it just jumps around. This is also well visible in your gif. When debug lines are turned on, you can see that they move smoothly, but the text jumps. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you are referring to the text jittering back and forth the that is caused by the font not being a monospaced font, so the total length of the text changes depending on what digits are being displayed. If you @Adixe swap the font out for one where all characters have the same width the problem goes away.

Comment: That's not quite my point. I mean the vibration of the font when changing the position of the body. The body changes its position smoothly, but the font seems to align itself to some kind of grid.

Comment: I did some tests. Calling the setUseIntegerPositions(false) method on the font helped. Thanks again for your help!